# In Child Activity, Fragment is recreated automatically - AppCompatViewInflater app:theme is now deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-appcompat

From MainActivity, i start a ChildActivity (which extends AppCompatActivity) with an intent.
The purpose of child activity is just to display some fragments (Welcome text then user can fill some edittext to enter his information).

```
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CreateUserActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, MainActivity.REQUEST_CREATE_PROFILE);
```

After a few seconds, in the activity, it is restarted...The view is reloaded.

So it is annoying, because if i am in the second fragment. The activity restart and i am back to the first one.
So my user have to restard his work.

I've got the following message in logcat when activity is recreated :

```
08-07 20:45:37.673    8010-8010/com.xxxxx.xxxxxI/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
```

Any idea ?

***ChildActivity code (relevant part):***

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     // Load the layout
        createToolbar();
        setUpProfile();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //super.onBackPressed();
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    private boolean createToolbar() {

        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer_white); //TODO : It isn't taking into account...default icon is not replaced - TODO : understand why ???
        mToolbar.setTitle("xxxxxx Toolbar");
        mToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_menubar_v3);
        mToolbar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.description));
        mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.navigation_icon_description));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);

        return true;
    }


        //If first time app is used, then user needs to create is profile process
        private boolean setUpProfile() {

            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);                            //Disable Orientation changes
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);                      //Disable Drawer
        WelcomeFragment myWelcomeFragment = WelcomeFragment.newInstance();
        disableEnableControls(false, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.root_linear_layout));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container3, myWelcomeFragment).commit();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue as well, and I have found that this is because of the custom support Toolbar you're using. If not necessary, try to stick to the conventional overflow menu

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to use conventional overflow menu. I need to use a custom Toolbar

Comment: check this website http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-android-creating-a-customized-toolbar--cms-24223